# Evaluating $\int \sqrt{\frac{3-x}{3+x}} \sin^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{3-x}{6}}\right)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Evaluate $$\int {\sqrt{\frac{3-x}{3+x}} \sin^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{3-x}{6}}\right)dx}$$

**My attempt**: I have used the substitution $x=3\cos 2\theta$ as it seemed appropriate on seeing the integrand. After simplification I got -$12\int \theta( \sin^2 \theta) d\theta $ which I was able to evaluate using integration by parts but I got a bit complicated answer. Was my approach correct? What other more efficient methods are there to evaluate this integral?

Comment: My mistake, thanks

Comment: Maybe helpful
$$
{\frac {3-x}{3+x}}=\frac{3-x}{6}+(\frac{3-x}{6})({\frac {3-x}{3+x}})
$$

Comment: Why is $x=3\cos 2 \theta$ a reasonable substitution?

Comment: @JavaMan, If you put $x=3\cos 2\theta$, then, $3-x=3-3\cos 2\theta=3(1-\cos 2\theta)=6\sin^2 \theta$ and $3+x=3+3\cos 2\theta=3(1+\cos 2\theta)=6\cos^2 \theta$. Thus the expression inside the first square root becomes $\frac{6\sin^2\theta}{6\cos^2\theta}$ which results in $\tan^2\theta$ and due to the square root, the result is $\tan\theta$.

Comment: The second square root simplifies to $\sin\theta$ and $dx=-6\sin 2\theta$. Thus, after complete substitution the integral becomes $\int (\tan\theta) (\sin^{-1}\sin\theta) (-6\sin 2\theta)d\theta=-12\int\theta (\sin^2\theta) d\theta$.

Comment: @MrAP Why do you want a simpler method?

Comment: @user108128 I was just wondering whether there is another method or not to evaluate this integral.

Comment: there are some methods for this but this one is simplest I think! Any way good job.